# Select a dropdown value using json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to select a drop-down value using json. I can easily pull data into my text input but how do I select a drop-down value?

http://plnkr.co/edit/R5RNruDNUydSJufVRIVh

Pull in the json:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log) {

  // bind json data to form
  $http.get('static.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.data = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // log error
  });

});
```

Put the json data into our form:

```
<h4>Select value 2 using json data</h4>

<select data-ng-model="data.myDropdown.value">
  <option value="">Select a value</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>


<hr />

<h4>I can pull in json data into text inputs but not dropdowns.</h4>

<p><input type="text" name="textData" data-ng-model="data.textData"></p>
```

The json:

```
{
  "textData":"Example text data",
  "myDropdown":"value 2"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model to:

```
<select data-ng-model="data.myDropdown">
```

And the value to:

```
<option value="value 2">Value 2</option>
```

working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zQR77KalooP1gUXRILV0

Answer (score 1):

First, `value` in `data-ng-model="data.myDropdown.value"` is not necessary. `data.myDropdown` is already a string so `.value` from it gives you `undefined`.

Second, the `<option>` is matched by the value, not by the text. So you either the JSON value should be changed to `2` or option's value should be changed to `value 2`.